# How do I optimally fuse nodes in a tree structure?

Tags: graphs, optimization, dynamic-programming, trees, algorithm-design

I am trying to solve the following problem. I've tried to find the name of this problem, but could not really find what I was looking for. I assume there should be some graph-theory that covers it, but it's been a while since my last algorithms class.

I do not need the global best solution, a "pretty good" solution should be fine.

##### Description

I have a tree with nodes containing some data. Semantically, some of this data belongs together, but is currently spread around the nodes of a subtree. I do not know which data belongs together, but I have some heuristic functions that take a subtree and indicate how likely (as in arbitrary tunable number, no probabilities going on here) it is, that all the information in this subtree actually belongs together.

If I think that the data in a subtree belongs together, I will fuse that subtree into a new node without any children and all the data that was part of the subtree.
If a subtree already contains a fused node, I can not fuse that subtree again.
I don't just want to fuse everything, since I want the resulting nodes to be as small as possible.
I want to find the modified tree, that best satisfies all the heuristics, while minimizing the fused nodes' sizes.

I've drawn a little example here:

[image: example trees]

##### My Solution

I am trying to solve this with dynamic programming (but absolutely don't have to if you have better ideas).
The algorithm that I have designed so far is:

1. traverse each node $n_i$ in post order.
   Compute 2 scores for each $n_i$ and memoize them:

   - The score if we fuse this node: the sum of all heuristics functions for the subtree starting at $n_i$, plus the scores if we didn't fuse all children
   - The score if we don't fuse this node: This is the sum off the maxima of both scores for each child
2. Backtrack from the root to find which score is higher in each node. If the "fuse score" is higher than the "don't fuse score", I fuse that node

##### Questions

I have several questions about this design. My questions are:

1. Is this a good way to solve this problem?
2. Are the scoring functions modeled in a sensible way? How could they be improved?
3. How do I integrate a penalty for fusing nodes so that they don't grow arbitrarily large? I would assume just subtract the weighted size of the data from the "fuse score"?
4. How do I tune the values that the scoring functions return and the penalty?

##### Questions from Comments answered

All of the constraints I have are a bit hand-wavy.
I am quickly going to explain what my actual use case is.

I have a HTML tree that renders some web page. Some elements in the rendered page semantically belong together, whereas others don't.
What belongs together depends on the context in which I am trying to solve this problem, and might change, but there are a few heuristics that could be useful.
For example:

- "everything underneath a *form* element probably belongs together"
- "everything within an element with the same border style probably belongs together"
- many more such indicators of varying complexity

I am trying to group the HTML of the page into semantic chunks

1. I can't tell you what the balance should be. My hunch is that I probably want to be on the more conservative side and fuse fewer things. I can't name a specific ratio, this would probably be a tunable parameter that is set after playing with it
2. I do want to maximize some objective function that rewards grouping together similar nodes, while also penalizes grouping together dissimilar nodes, and penalizes grouping too large subtrees (in the worst case, grouping at the root gives me no useful information). I could also add scoring heuristics that somehow measure dissimilarity, if that helps.

Comment: This may well be an interesting problem, but for now it's impossible to know how to solve it, since you haven't provided any indication on how the constraints work together. One (the want for keeping nodes small) should discourage contracting the subtrees, while the other (maximizing the function you mentioned) should encourage it. But you should put a number on what the balance between these two constraints ought to be, otherwise we don't have a mathematical problem to solve.

Comment: Also, you haven't at all defined how to "best satify the heuristics". I suppose you want to maximize some objective function that rewards grouping together similar nodes, while also penalizes grouping together dissimilar nodes? This needs to be defined if you want to solve it algorithmically. And by the way, I'm curious how how "similar" nodes are defined, as well. Is it an equivalence relation, or something more fluid? Given a grouping of data points, can you easily see whether they all belong together or not?

Comment: @Highheath I've answered your questions in the edited question

Comment: It might be better not to frame this as an optimization problem, and simply go with a rule-based solution.